# How do I fix the CLS issue which Google Search Console Reports

Tags: search, console, core-web-vitals

Although Individual URLs score are good but in a group (as per GSC) these urls fail in CLS check.
how do I check and come up with some recommendation for the tech team!

Also, please tell me what data points can I provide in order for you to check (in case you want to)

TTFB seems to be the issue with FCP and CLS problems in GSC but not sure anymore.

Answer (score 0):

An initial check is just to watch a page load. Do you see things move around as they load? Slowing down your network connection via the browsers dev tools can help make the movements easier to spot.

The performance tool in Chrome is good at highlighting layout shifts.

Answer (score 0):

GSC will highlight the pages most contributing to that group score if you click on it, in order of page views. See the example below (for LCP rather than CLS but principal is the same):

[image: Screenshot of Core Web Vitals report in Google Search Console]

You can then click on the three dots and run a PageSpeed Insights report on each URL which will identify any page load CLS issues. Be aware however that CLS can also happen after page load which PSI will not highlight.

Once you have identified the issue, there is plenty of documentation online about how to optimise CLS. For example:

- https://web.dev/optimize-cls/
- https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/06/how-to-fix-cumulative-layout-shift-issues/